# URL redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect following url with htaccess, but cant find the right solution:

```
/claroline/index.php?logout=true **to** /index.php?route=user/logout
```

Comment: Do you want an silent/internal redirect or an external redirect ?

Comment: Is `/claroline/` a real directory?

Comment: @JustinIurman external would be ok.

Comment: @anubhava yes, it's real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in your `/claroline/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /claroline/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^logout=true$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?route=user/logout [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```